# Installing/using CGAL on Windows with QT

Tags: windows, qt, msbuild, cgal

Firstly I want to say that I am relatively new to coding, so this question may appear pretty dumb to any programmer with experience.

Background: 
I created a program that converts images of an object and creates a point-cloud which replicates the surface of this object. So far - so good, it works decently. The next step is to use a surface reconstruction algorithm so that I can convert this point-cloud to a "shape" and essentially store it as a .stl file, which is why I want to use CGAL.

I use QT 5.9 on Windows 7 - 64 Bit

Problem: 
Though it should be easy (in theory) to use a different library when coding in c/c++, I failed miserably to "instal" CGAL and I don't have an idea how to proceed with this.

Most of the tutorials I found were for MSVC and Windows, still, I tried to follow them but it got me nowhere.

Here is what I tried (following the "official" instructions [link](https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html#PrerequisitesforBuildingthe64-bitCGALLibraryUsingMicrosoftVisualStudio):

- Downloaded CGAL and Cmake, and then wanted to "build" CGAL
  I selected the right folders etc. but when selecting a compiler I always got an error.
  No matter which one of the MSVC-Compilers I used, Cmake always told me "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

  MSBuild.exe"
  saying it couldn't find that executable, though I installed the MSVC Compilers while installing QT.

Then I figured, that I'm not using MSVC but QT so maybe I should build CGAL with MINGW, the compiler I use on QT, but also got an error saying "Cmake_make program is not set. You probably need to select a different build tool"

So.. how do I get to use CGAL-classes and functions in my program?

Also more of a global question, why is it so difficult to do when you usually just need to tell QT or Visual Studio where abc.h and abc.cpp lie.

Hope you can help me and thank you in advance!

Comment: What's you cmake command when trying to compile with MINGW?

Comment: I was using the cmake-gui, just pressed configure to select the compiler and these were the results. Here is the full line: CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.

Comment: The first pb here is not related to CGAL but on how to use cmake with mingw. You should probably look for that on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The [official instruction](https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html) is good enough though it is out-of-date. I successfully built the latest v4.11 on Windows 10 64-bits with latest Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and other latest Boost, Qt, and libQGLViewer.

I found [this instruction](https://qiita.com/pikattoo/items/bcd6fb631868af512bff) useful though it does not include Qt and libQGLViewer installation which are needed for examples and demo.

If you want the examples and demo, you have to install Qt and libQGLViewer. If you don't have any experience with Qt, please install it correctly. The default setup does not include the things you may need such as the kit for MSVC2017 64bit or MinGW 32bit which has to be selected during the setup.

By the way, following the [official instruction](https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html), I found a problem when building the libQGLViewer. If you meet this problem too, just don't build it with those commands. You need to install [Qt Visual Studio Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123) in Visual Studio and lunch the .pro with Visual Studio and build it in debug and release modes. Finally, don't forget to config the environment variable.